# Django - Link to download bringing me a past file

Tags: django, cookies

I have a regular Django project working fine for year and links for many download Microsoft Excel templates.

The thing is I've change one of them, and when I click to download it, it downloads me the older spreadsheet (I've deleted it on my server). But if I access on an incognito browser, it downloads me the newest version.

What should I do to solve this, is it something related to time expiration of cookies or something like this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the file without changing the name server serves it as attachment, browser should believe you are serving same file and use the brower cache instead or really download the file for increasing performance and bandwidth. If you are using an incognito browser, there is no cache, so browser really download the file serve by Django

Solution can be to serve with a different name or including in the name the created datetime of the file or... etc

Comment: Thank you! This what I've already done to solve it. I was asking in case it's a better solution to this. Thanks!!

Comment: this is the solution, the way to create a different file name for each file update, it is your choice, there are many solution, no one better than others

Comment: you can mark question as answered if it ok :)